# Are Shared Projects a good way to add C# code to a VB.NET-based Office VSTO add-in solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsto, office-addins

For an Office VSTO written in VB.NET I would like to add some C# functions that can be written more cleanly in C# (for instance using pattern matching).

I understand there is the option to add a Shared C# Project to a VB.NET VSTO solution (I tried it and VS lets me add it without errors), this is possible although not documented well by Microsoft see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows) (as you will see the links to the general documentation about Shared Projects no longer work).

I am the only one writing the code, I would prefer to keep everything in one solution to be able to quickly switch between the VB.NET and C# code when working on the solution, so a .NET class library in C# isn't the ideal option.

Are Shared Projects a good way to add C# code this way or am I overlooking some pretty big drawbacks? Thank you for sharing your insights!

Comment: What is wrong with a class library? You should be able to use C# classes from VB.Net, and your C# code can use Outlook objects just fine.

Comment: I’m doing this regularly and, as Dmitri states, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Shared C# Project is a multiplatform solution which is not required in case of VSTO add-ins. COM add-ins are supported on Windows only. There is no COM technology available on other platforms. So, you can use a regular class library project in case of VSTO add-ins. See [Tutorial: Create a .NET class library using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-6-0) for more information.

Comment: Eugene I followed your answer and added a C# class library project for .NET Standard 2.0 to the VB.NET VSTO solution. I had to upgrade the VSTO target .NET from 4.0 client profile to 4.8 for .NET Standard 2.0 compatibility and it works well now thank you!